# How is the "intraclass-correlation" related to the covariance matrices of the random-effects and residuals in a mixed-effects model?

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, random-effects-model, covariance-matrix, intraclass-correlation

How is the intraclass-correlation related to the covariance matrix of the random-effects and residuals?

> Beginning with Ronald Fisher, the intraclass correlation has been regarded within the framework of analysis of variance (ANOVA), and more recently random effects model
> $$
> Y_{i j}=\mu+\alpha_j+\varepsilon_{i j}
> $$
> and $\varepsilon_{i j}$ is an unobserved noise term. ${ }^{[5]}$ For the model to be identified, the $\alpha_j$ and $\varepsilon_{i j}$ are assumed to have expected value zero and to be uncorrelated with each other. Also, the $\alpha_j$ are assumed to be identically distributed, and the $\varepsilon_{i j}$ are assumed to be identically distributed. The variance of $\alpha_j$ is denoted $\sigma_a^2$ and the variance of $\varepsilon_{i j}$ is denoted $\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2$.
> The population ICC in this framework is ${ }^{[6]}$
> $$
> \frac{\sigma_\alpha^2}{\sigma_\alpha^2+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}
> $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation

Comment: IIUC, you have provided the formula $\frac{\sigma_\alpha^2}{\sigma_\alpha^2 + \sigma_\epsilon^2}$ that answers your question. Could you clarify what exactly you want to know?

Comment: Intraclass correlation (in the context of multilevel/mixed models) refers to the proportion of variance in your outcome measure attributable to the random effect (clustering factor). For instance, in a study with 1000 students from 20 schools as participants, you'd want to include school as a random effect in your model. Intraclass correlation would be the proportion of school-related variance out of total variance in your outcome.

Comment: Do we ever use ICC alternative to hausman test?

Comment: I haven't used the Hausman test, but from what I can see it seems to be used to determine whether a multilevel (mixed model) regression is needed or whether you can use a single-level (OLS) regression. ICC derived from an unconditional multilevel regression can also be used for this purpose, but it is (IMO) usually used less formally - if ICC is not negligible, the random effect needs to be added to the model.